# Sending webhook data from server to client in real-time

Tags: express, webhooks

I have an express server running and I'm serving files locally like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

I've also set up a webhook and I'm receiving the data correctly on the following route:

```
app.post('/callback', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).end()
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

My question is how do I display the data that I'm currently console logging on the client side? When data comes in I want to show a real-time notification on the front-end.

This is my first time working with server development and webhooks, so apologies if this is painfully obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about how webhooks work. Webhooks are for **server-to-server** communication. To send the data to the client's browser in real-time, you may want to use WebSockets.

Comment: Server sent events is best approach.
He only needs to send data from server to client.

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

`res.send(req.body)`.

That will output the body in your response.

Comment: This will send the response to the server that is sending the data via webhooks and not the client